# Direct Torque Control of Induction Motor (DTC)

Tags: driver, power-electronics, matlab, induction-motor, simulink

I was working on a project on how to design a classical Direct Torque Control drive DTC but there is a ceratin point that i can't understand. How can we calculate the Reference values of the torque and speed out from the speed ?

Comment: Please give us more information on what you're trying to work out.

Answer (score 1):

The speed reference is set by the operator. The torque reference is derived from speed error. The actual motor speed and torque are calculated from the motor voltage current and frequency using vector quantities of current and voltage. The voltage vector is determined from the DC link voltage and the switching pattern. The current vector is determined from current sensor signals. The motor equivalent circuit parameters and performance ratings are also used in the calculation.